# Youtube API - нужно по ссылке получить title и продолжительность видео

Tags: php, youtube-api

Надо по ссылке на видео получить его `title` и `duration` через PHP. Youtube предлагает использовать Gdata но как же найти этот класс и отдельно его использовать?

Comment: [Get youtube title from videoid in PHP using API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769747/get-youtube-title-from-videoid-in-php-using-api-v3).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1111680/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be-youtube/1112452#1112452

Answer (score 3, accepted):

с недавнего времени работа с api данного сервиса доступна только через
https://developers.google.com/youtube/