# Как правильно получить прямую ссылку на видео YouTube?

Tags: php, json

Подскажите как правильно получить прямую ссылку (или как отправить запрос через cURL) на видео в YouTube.
Сейчас делаю так, получаю meta информацию так [https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=айди_видео](https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE) с помощью `$data = file_get_contents("https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=айди_видео");`

Там нахожу ссылку на видео, но по какой-то причине, некоторые видео ссылки не предоставляют, а получаю вот такой ответ: `{"playabilityStatus":{"status":"UNPLAYABLE","reason":"Это видео недоступно.","errorScreen":{"playerErrorMessageRenderer":{"reason":{"simpleText":"Это видео недоступно."},"proceedButton":{"buttonRenderer":{"style":"STYLE_PRIMARY","size":"SIZE_DEFAULT","isDisabled":false,"text":{"simpleText":"Посмотреть на YouTube"},"trackingParams":"CAQQ8FsiEwjU34jNju_oAhWNdbIKHSxYDQA="}},"thumbnail":{"thumbnails":[{"url":"//s.ytimg.com/yts/img/meh7-vflGevej7.png","width":140,"height":100}]},"icon":{"iconType":"ERROR_OUTLINE"}}},"contextParams":"Q0FFU0FnZ0M="},"videoDetails"`

По какой причине? Видео доступно для просмотра на YouTube. Не могу понять.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно получить ссылку через meta или как обращаться по-другому к YouTube, чтобы получить прямую ссылку и инфо о видео. **Спасибо**.

Answer (score 1):

Всю инфу о видео можешь получить так:

```
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsBc3Ipo4Fc';
//$url = 'https://youtu.be/qsBc3Ipo4Fc';
$id = NULL;

preg_match('/[\?\&]v=([^\&]*)/', $url, $ok);
if(!empty($ok[1])){
    $id = trim($ok[1]);
};

if(empty($id)){
    preg_match('/youtu\.be\/([^\&]*)/', $url, $ok);
    if(!empty($ok[1])){
        $id = trim($ok[1]);
    };
};

if(!empty($id)){
    
    $strm = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'method' => 'GET',
            'header' => 'referer: https://www.youtube.com/'
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($strm);
    $content = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?html5=1&video_id='.$id, false, $context);      
    
    parse_str($content, $arr);
    if(is_array($arr)){
        foreach($arr as &$v){
            $v = rawurldecode($v);
            if(is_object(json_decode($v))){
                $v = json_decode($v, true);
            };
        };
    };
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arr);
    echo '</pre>';
```